Get a text to a string variable from a dropdowndatawindow in powerbuilder 9.0
I trying this
long ll_row
string matricula
ll_row = dw_2.getrow()
matricula = dw_2.getitemstring(row, 'COD_VACUM')

MessageBox('Aviso', matricula)

I want to do a retrieve where I get the data related to Cod_vacum, but when I click the dropdown, just get another values, but not that I want, so can someone help me please? I'm learning and I can't find any documentation reference of this problem in the web., Sorry for my bad English my main language is Spanish.
I changed the retrieve, for a MessageBox, to know which value is getting "matricula", but never get the value that I need and I didn't understand why.
I just need understand why the row selected, doesn't match with the text that I need to select.

Already Solved, i used matricula = dw_2.GetText() and this solved the problem.

you should add this as an answer even if it's your own question, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467
